# UITabBar is not align on top?

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios5

I'm using UITabBarController in my app. Originally I started the app from SDK 4.3 and then I moved to SDK 5.0. For some reason I need to change my code, to work on the new SDK. So, I changed the code

From this

```
self.view = tabController.view;
```

To this

```
[self.view addSubview:tabController.view];
```

Now the tabController switch from view to subView it's not aligning properly.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITabBarController should be use directly on the UIWindow, the gap you're seeing is because it automatically places it self above the status bar.

I think the best solution is to do this in your app delegate:

```
[window addSubview:[tabController view]];
```

Or you could change the tabController's view's frame :

```
tabController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(tabController.view.frame, 0, -20)
[self.view addSubview:tabController.view];
```

The magic 20 is the height of the status bar.

Comment: Thank you, works great! Small change on your code "tabController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(tabController.view.frame, 0, -20);" -20 should be on y axis.